# run foreach loop via parallel to build result list

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am looping thro data from tblCustomer and checking if the address is valid or not. If not, then I am adding this to my return list.
The problem, there are 37000 rows to validate. The validation is done via external library. It's taking about 1hr. I want to do this threaded so I can do it much faster.
Can someone help me rewrite it? Also I read somewhere to wrap this in parallel class for or foreach. Few things that I am wondering -

1. how many threads will it create? how can we control that?
2. can we say how many records each thread will process?
3. and I think the most imp question: this dll has static class that will validate the address. Is it going to give me any performance gain when I split it into threads..or will it take the same time?

---

```
 List<tblCustomer> customers = new List<tblCustomer>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var customer in DataContext.tblCustomers)
            {
                string addressToValidate = string.Format("{0}, {1}; {2} {3}", GetSafeString(customer.MailingCity), GetSafeString(customer.MailingState), GetSafeString(customer.MailingAddress), GetSafeString(customer.MailingAddress2));
                isTripValid = PCM.PCMSAddStop(tripId, addressToValidate.Trim()) == 1;
                if (!isTripValid)
                { 
                    customers.Add(customer);
                }
                i++;
                if (i == 1000)
                {
                    PCM.PCMSClearStops(tripId);
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            PCM.PCMSCloseServer(serverID);
            PCM.PCMSDeleteTrip(tripId);

            return customers;
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx should be able to help.

Comment: Async is not what I am looking for. Even if the UI thread is locked for a few minutes I am okay with that. As long as it's fast. Right now it takes upto 60 min. :(

Answer (score 1):

1. You can control the number of threads using the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property on the [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) class.

   ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5; //Limit the concurrent threads to 5
2. You can control the partitioning by using the [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604.aspx) overload which takes a Partitioner<> object as a parameter.

   [Here's a great article with an example on partitioning](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/custom-parallel-partitioning-with-net-4/224600406?pgno=2)
3. It probably will improve your performance still, but it's hard to know how much until you try it.

Note: if you're going to start using multiple threads make sure all of your shared objects/lists are threadsafe.  For example, you'll need to either put a lock around your customers List or use a collection from the ConcurrentCollections namespace.  Are the PCM methods threadsafe?

Comment: From what I understand, they are thread safe. can you please show me example of code you are saying in 1 and 2?

Comment: I haven't actually written my own partitioner, but I've put in a link to a great article on it which has examples.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Does anyone have an example similar to my question and got it working?